# twilio error 2 factor authentication says I have reached the limit to resend the code only when via call

Tags: authentication, twilio, two-factor-authentication

I've been unable to login to twilio for the last few days. I'm stuck during the two factor authentication process. When I use the SMS option, my phone doesn't receive the message even after several attempts. This morning I tried to request the code via call but it says `You have reached the limit to resend the code. Please use another method or try again later.` but this is the first time I've tried requesting the code via call. The SMS option worked fine until a couple weeks ago so I have never needed to use the call option.

What can I do to login to my twilio account?

Comment: I’m sorry you’re having technical difficulties. If you have issues logging in with 2FA, this probably means there is something wrong in the backend. I’d recommend reaching out to Twilio Support.